# Change meaning of established tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki

I just checked the [managed](/questions/tagged/managed) tag wiki and it's all about the Common Language Runtime and C#/VB.net.

Even though the term was coined by Microsoft for the CLR and related languages, I would argue that the term *managed* is more generic than that, as also Java is a "managed" language, as well as (arguably) script languages such as Python.

Would edits of the tag-wiki to make it more generalized be welcome? Especially considering it's pretty established with over 550 questions marked with the tag.

Comment: +1 for asking before going and editing, personally I think you should check the existing questions; if many of them are about other meanings then yes it's worth mentioning this in the wiki.

Comment: its not always about what the keyword on tag means - it's how to use it within the context of SO which is a programming oriented site. So a `blender` couldn't relate to a [blender](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&docid=IglUicqakSQsPM&tbnid=ei0R2iOiufrwrM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amara.com%2Fshop%2Fblenders-juicers&ei=-omLUqP6BMLP0QWTg4GoAg&bvm=bv.56643336,d.ZG4&psig=AFQjCNEG6YuLJ83xW_MQ95_mqTZfYhNsSw&ust=1384962936777812)

Comment: Sounds like a meta-ish question that should be burned.  Do you have any examples where its use is appropriate to the question?

Comment: @mehow your link gives "Redirect Notice" warning. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd *pictures!* @ https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=blender

Comment: All the languages you mention are similar in having a runtime but only .Net has documentation saying managed

Comment: I'm not fond of these general words that are co-opted to mean something more specific.  They're always trouble.  Can we change it to [managed-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code)?